# Habilitar botões em colunas de uma tabela com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, table

Eu preciso habilitar os botões da linha de uma tabela cujo o conteúdo da primeira coluna seja igual ao valor que eu tenho em uma variável. Já tentei de várias formas mas não dá certo

Segue o código:

```
$("body").delegate('#btnFecharCaixaEditaEvento', 'click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var idEvento = 20;
    $('#tabEventos').find('tr').each( function(i,el){
        var identEvento = $(this).find('td').text();
        if( identEvento==idEvento ){
            $(this).eq(2).prop( 'disabled',false );
            $(this).eq(3).prop( 'disabled',false );
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

e o html:

```
<table id='tabEventos' class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-responsive' >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>ID</b></th>
            <th><b>Horário</b></th>
            <th class='text-center' colspan='2'><b>Equipamentos</b></th>
            <th class='text-center' colspan='2'><b>Serviços</b></th>
            <th><b>Observações</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='text-right'>10</td>
            <td>07:00-10:00</td>
            <td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#cxEditaEquipRes' disabled='disabled'>Incluir</button></td>
            <td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' id='viewEquipamentos'>Ver</button></td>
            <td>blablabla</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='text-right'>20</td>
            <td>07:00-10:00</td>
            <td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#cxEditaEquipRes' disabled='disabled'>Incluir</button></td>
            <td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' id='viewEquipamentos'>Ver</button></td>
            <td>blablabla</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='text-right'>30</td>
            <td>07:00-10:00</td>
            <td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#cxEditaEquipRes' disabled='disabled'>Incluir</button></td>
            <td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' id='viewEquipamentos'>Ver</button></td>
            <td>blablabla</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duas mudanças no teu código:

- usa `'td:first'` para te dar somente o primeiro elemento `td`
- usa `$(this).find('button').removeAttr('disabled');` para encontrar esse elemento `button` e `.removeAttr()` para remover o atributo.

Resultado:

```
$('#tabEventos').find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    var identEvento = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    if (identEvento == idEvento) {
        $(this).find('button').removeAttr('disabled');
        return false;
    }
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hq0756ye/

Comment: Olá Sergio. Agradeço pela informação. Deu certinho. Ele desabilita todos os botões da linha. Agora tem como eu desabilitar os botões somente de uma faixa de colunas ? Por exemplo os botões que estão entre a coluna 7 à coluna 10 ?

Comment: @Francisco sim, quando usas `$(this).find('button').each(function(i` dentro desse `.each` que coloquei na resposta, esse `i` é o numero da coluna começando em 0. Assim podes criar um `if` para verificar isso.

Comment: blz. Sergio. Vou tentar fazer a condição. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Então Sergio. Esse i que vc comentou na verdade é o contador das linhas, pra contar as colunas eu fiz outro each dentro do if:       $(this).find('td').each( function(indice){
       if( indice>=8 && indice<=13 ){
        $(this).find('button').removeAttr('disabled');
        
       }
      }); Mas suas dicas ajudaram muito. Tô só publicando o código final pra que possa ajudar outros com a mesma dúvida. abs